# Is the weak topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ the same as the box topology?

Tags: general-topology, box-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be the subset of $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ consisting of all sequences which are nonzero for only finitely many terms.  Give $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ the weak topology, that is, $A\subset \mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ is open iff $A\cap \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for each $n$.  Is $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ with the box topology?

The reason why I think this is true is because it looks like the box topology is the weak topology with respect to the natural inclusions $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ [Edit: I have doubts about this particular claim.]

Comment: What have you tried? Have you attempted anything using the definitions, for example? This sounds a lot like you're asking for an answer to a homework or exam problem without showing any effort.

Comment: @Steve Kass Homework...on Christmas Eve...

Comment: @SihOASHoihd: Well, it’s not *absolutely* impossible: my linear algebra final my first semester in college back in 1965 was a take-home over Christmas break. :-) But I’ve no problem with the question: you did in fact offer some evidence of having thought about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the weak topology and the box topology on $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ are the same.  One direction is easy: it is clear that every basic open subset in the box topology has open intersection with each $\mathbb{R}^n$ and so is open in the weak topology.

The converse requires more work.  Let me first remark that both topologies are translation-invariant: this is obvious for the box topology, and for the weak topology, it follows from the fact that any translate of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by an element of $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ is contained in $\mathbb{R}^N$ for some $N$.  Now suppose $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^\infty$ is an open neighborhood of a point $p$ in the weak topology; we may translate to assume $p$ is the origin.  Then $U\cap\mathbb{R}$ contains some interval $[-\epsilon_1,\epsilon_1]$.  Since $[-\epsilon_1,\epsilon_1]$ is compact, openness of $U\cap\mathbb{R}^2$ implies it actually contains a box $[-\epsilon_1,\epsilon_1]\times[-\epsilon_2,\epsilon_2]$ by the tube lemma.  Continuing this process, we get a sequence $(\epsilon_n)$ of positive numbers such that $U\cap\mathbb{R}^n$ contains $\prod_{i=1}^n[-\epsilon_i,\epsilon_i]$ for each $n$.  This implies that $U$ contains $\prod_{i=1}^\infty(-\epsilon_i,\epsilon_i)\cap\mathbb{R}^\infty$ and so is a neighborhood of the origin in the box topology as well.

(Alternatively, instead of using a translation to assume $p$ is the origin, we could have started by picking $n$ such that $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and taking a compact neighborhood $K$ of $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ contained in $U\cap\mathbb{R}^n$, and then found a set of the form $K\times\prod[-\epsilon_i,\epsilon_i]$ contained in $U$.)

More generally, a similar argument shows that given a sequence of locally compact pointed spaces $(X_n)$, the box topology on the "direct sum" $\bigoplus X_n$ (i.e. the subset of the product $\prod X_n$ consisting of points which are the basepoint on all but finitely many coordinates) is the same as the colimit topology considering $\bigoplus X_n$ as the colimit of the finite products.

Comment: To apply the tube lemma the way you do, don't you need to know that $U\cap ([-\epsilon_{1},\epsilon_{1}] \times \mathbb{R})$ contains a slice of the form $\{x_{0}\}\times [-N,N]$?

Comment: By our choice of $\epsilon_1$, we know that $U\cap\mathbb{R}^2$ contains $[-\epsilon_1,\epsilon_1]\times\{0\}$.  So, it must contain $[-\epsilon_1,\epsilon_1]\times[\epsilon_2,-\epsilon_2]$ for some $\epsilon_2>0$.

Comment: @EricWofsey I do not quite understand how $[-\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_1]\subseteq U\cap \mathbb{R}$ implies that $[-\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_1]\times \{0\} \subseteq U\cap \mathbb{R}^2.$ Wouldn't you need to make $\varepsilon_1$ potentially smaller?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven: That is true by definition (though we are abusing notation here so your misunderstanding is understandable).  Here $\mathbb{R}^n$ really refers to the subset $\mathbb{R}^n\times\{(0,0,0,\dots)\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^\infty$.  So $\mathbb{R}$ is identified with the subset $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I was thinking about projections the whole time.

Comment: @EricWofsey I follow you now